# Integrating Skye for Business 2015 with Exchange online (365)

Tags: microsoft-office-365, skype-for-business-2016

I'm attempting to integrate Skype for Business 2015 with Exchange online (365).
I already have my Skype for Business environment set up.
I also had Exchange 2016 On-Prem set up and integrated with Skype for Business 2015.
- I have followed the steps to integrate Lync (Skype for business) with exchange online (http://lyncinsider.com/unified-communications/how-to-connect-lync-server-to-exchange-online-part-1/)
- I have changed DNS records on godaddy.
- I gave my user an E3 developer on 365.

I did not follow the dialplan steps in the guide (linked above) as we do not use phones, only Skype for Business clients.

I noticed I still get the internal EWS from the old exchange (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF1uB.jpg) 
I'm currently lost and I'm not sure how to continue as it seems that I'm still not integrated with Exchange online.

Thanks to anyone who is able to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I have been able to solve this.

I had to run the Exchange Hybrid configuration like it has been done in this video:
https://youtu.be/qTDjg2C6jvA?t=206

Afterwards when connecting to Skype for Business I had an exchange pop-up for inserting the password (which means I have connected to 365).